# ラベル名が異なる場合のmergeについて

Tags: python, python3, pandas

以下の表のように、
同じ意味でラベル名が異なっている2つのデータフレームを結合しようと
した場合、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

通常だと、以下のような答えになるかと思うのですが・・・
pd.merge(A,B,on="日付")

ちなみに、日付、Dateそれぞれindexとして定義してあります。

---

```
A
    日付   価格
2000-01-05 100
2000-01-06 110 
2000-01-07 120

B
    Date   price
2000-01-05 50
2000-01-06 60
2000-01-08 70
```

Comment: `left_on` と `right_on` を使って、`pd.merge(A, B, how='left', left_on='日付', right_on='Date')` とすると良いかと思います。結合の仕方は `how` で指定できます(デフォルト値は `inner` で、 その他に `left`, `right`, `outer`)。

Answer (score 1):

「ラベル名が異なる場合のmergeについて」⇒ラベル名を合わせろ！では回答になってないと思いますが
結果が欲しいなら下記の方法でできます。
indexとカラム名を変更して、concatでマージします。

```
import pandas as pd
dateA = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-05','2000-01-06','2000-01-07'],name='日付')
dateB = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-05','2000-01-06','2000-01-08'],name='Date')

A = pd.DataFrame({'価格':[100,110,120]},index=dateA)
B = pd.DataFrame({'price':[50,60,70]},index=dateB)

tmp = B.rename_axis('日付') #indexの名前を変える
tmp = tmp.rename(index=str, columns={'price': '価格'}) #columnの名前を変える
tmp = pd.concat([A, tmp], ignore_index=False) # concatでマージ
AB = tmp
```

ABに結果は、入っていますが日付が同じものがあるので、以下追加して

```
tmp['日付'] = tmp.index # AとBで日付が重複しているので違うなにかの価格とするとindexにいると扱いにくいので
tmp.index = range(len(tmp.index)) #日付をcolumnに追い出す
tmp = tmp[['日付','価格']] # columnの順番入れ替え
AB = tmp.sort_values(by=['日付'], ascending=True) #日付でソート
```

多分、こういうコードを書きたくないので１操作で出来る方法を質問したとおもいますので
スマートな回答があるまではこちらを使えばマージはできます。

Answer (score 1):

> ちなみに、日付、Dateそれぞれindexとして定義してあります

であれば、パラメータに , left_index=True と right_index=True　を渡すだけではないでしょうか

```
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'価格':[100,110,120]},
                    index=pd.Index(pd.date_range('20000105', periods=3, freq='d'), name='日付'))
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'price':[50,60,70]},
                    index=pd.Index(pd.date_range('20000105', periods=3, freq='d'), name='Date'))
print(pd.merge(df_A, df_B, left_index=True, right_index=True))
#             価格  price
#日付
#2000-01-05  100     50
#2000-01-06  110     60
#2000-01-07  120     70
```